# Are 2 page login processes more secure?

Tags: security, authentication, web

I've noticed recently that some major online services (google, yahoo) are using a 2 page process to log users in. The first page asks for a user name and then once submitted a second page then requests the password.

Whats the reasoning behind doing it this way? Is it more secure?

Comment: Perhaps more appropriate for http://security.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

There might be more to it than this, but:

Google for work integrates Google services with a custom domain. In such setups, it is possible that the authentication is handled by company's own LDAP (or whatever) server. In such cases, after entering the email, user is redirected to log in at their company's site rather than Google.

So, in general, it allows the actual authentication to be handled somewhere else according to the given username.